# Finding the radius and extreme coordinate points of the circles(Hough Circle Transform)

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

I need to find the extreme points of the circles from this image ( the top-left corner,top-right corner,the bottom-left corner and lastly the bottom-right corner)

The image go through threshold then canny edge detection before overlaying back to the original image.

[image]
for example ( drew via paint)

[image]

and connect them together ( drew via paint)

[image]

[image]

but how am I suppose to get the radius and the  x and y coordinate from the centre first and then draw the line?

```
for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
{
    //icout << i<<"\n"<<endl;
    Point center(cvRound(circles[i][ 0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
    stringstream ss;
    ss << i + 1;
    putText(dst, ss.str(), center, 1, 1, Scalar(255, 0, 225 ), 2, 0);
    int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    // circle center
    circle(src, center, 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);
    // circle outline
    circle(src, center, radius, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);
    //for original image overlap
    circle(dst, center, 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);
    // circle outline
    circle(dst, center, radius, Scalar(0, 255, 255), 3, 8, 0);


}
```

this is the demo code but i'm struggling to understand about the
 circles.size()
from

```
for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
```

and

```
Point center(cvRound(circles[i][ 0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
```

i'll appreciate it if you could explain it to me in a more simpler way as i'm still in my learning process,just a starting point for me to start will do.
Thanks!

Comment: not exactly an answer to your question, but might a convex hull of all the circles the be solution to what you originally wanted? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html

Comment: @Micka Yes! That's exactly what i'm looking for except I just need the outline. Am I able to change it color so that i'm able to threshold it to get only the outline without the inner contours? I'm not so sure what the rng.uniform(0,255) does though and why does it need 3 of them :l

Comment: try `for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
      {
        Scalar color = Scalar( 0, 0, 255 );
        drawContours( drawing, hull, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
      }
` to draw only the hull in full red color. The rng code is a random number generator, so the tutorial code will draw in random color!

Comment: the important code is ` convexHull( Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false );` this will compute the outline. But previously you have to combine all your circle contours to a single contour.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to combine my circles result into a single contour then use the convexHull method again!

Comment: @Micka Do you mean like grouping all the circle into a contour so that the convexHull will be able to capture the corners?

Comment: imho it is sufficient to push back all the circle contour points (or even the "extreme points" of the circles you mentioned) unordered to a std::vector<cv::Point> because the ordering isn't necessary for convex hull computation afaik.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to show the definition of circles, i.e. what type is circles

it looks like it might be a `vector<vector<int>>` (or some form of `tuple<int>`)

unless I misunderstand your question `circles.size()` is the number of circles and not the radius of a circle  (`size()`) being a function that returns the number of elements in a vector

the inner `vector<int>` seems to be storing the x position in `[0]` and the y position in `[1]`

and the radius of the circle in [2]

Comment: Thanks! Managed to understand a little better :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the opencv doc on Circle hough transform http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles

under the variable **circles** you can see that it is a vector were each circle is a 3 tuple with values (x,y,radius)

So in your case to get the data of circle i:

xCoordinate = circles[i][0]

yCoordinate = circles[i][1]

radius = circles[i][2]

circles.size(): is the number of circles that were found.

After that in order to find the lower left point for example just look for the 6 points with the lowest y coordinate and from that group look for the one with the smallest x coordinate.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get the x and y coordinates but what do you mean by "the 6 points with the lowest y coordinate" ?

Comment: create a vector for all the y coordinates of the circles. Than sort it (and get the indexes) and take the values of the 6 circles with the lowest y coordinate. For those circles find the circle which has the lowest x coordinate.

Comment: Sorry, i'm really a slow learner but for now I first created a vector and then add the x and y coordinate into the list inside the circles.size for loop

 vector<Point> data;
data.push_back(Point(circles[i][0], circles[i][1]));